# Getting blank page after deploying ASP.NET MVC application on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC application on my windows 10 system IIS. I have given full permission to **IIS_IUSRS** of both the root folder and web.config file. i.e.

[image]

My web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="http://localhost:61681/api/" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      <pages>
          <namespaces>
              <add namespace="Online.Common.Admin" />
          </namespaces>
      </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.csharpcodeprovider, microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35" warninglevel="4" compileroptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.vbcodeprovider, microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35" warninglevel="4" compileroptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_mytype=\&quot;web\&quot; /optioninfer+" />
      </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: E2BBCD58-DEC6-4A53-9CFE-FCFA11E6EBDB-->
```

Application in my IIS is like:

[image]

But when i go to **http://localhost/test123123** i get a blank page. What can be the issue, i am stuck on it for 5 hours now.

In logs i have this:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-07-04 18:16:33
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-07-04 18:16:33 192.168.10.8 GET /bmlinks/ddf.xml - 80 - 192.168.10.8 avast!+Antivirus - 404 0 64 11900
2020-07-04 18:16:33 192.168.10.8 GET /upnp/BasicDevice.xml - 80 - 192.168.10.8 avast!+Antivirus - 404 0 64 9898
2020-07-04 18:16:34 192.168.10.8 GET / - 80 - 192.168.10.8 avast!+Antivirus - 200 0 64 29749
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-07-04 18:39:05
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-07-04 18:39:05 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.116+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 3613
2020-07-04 18:39:05 ::1 GET /iisstart.png - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.116+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/ 200 0 0 43
2020-07-04 18:39:05 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.116+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/ 404 0 2 4
2020-07-04 18:47:30 ::1 GET /test123123 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.102+Safari/537.36+Edge/18.18362 - 500 19 5 87
2020-07-04 18:51:51 ::1 GET /test123123 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.102+Safari/537.36+Edge/18.18362 - 500 19 5 1
```

Browser console is :

[image]

Comment: How about iis logs. Is something logged over there?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad added logs file contents in the question

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: You get a 500 server error on hitting the specified url. Nothing much over there. Can you create a new website and run it on a different port and see if it works.

Comment: Browser console is added in the question @DurgaPrasad

Comment: Have you checked the event log for any .NET errors? It looks like your app is loading but it's throwing an error, the logs don't show a call stack but event viewer might give some context

Comment: 500 is always a server issue. Meaning you have to look in logs server side.  But it could be caused by client side passing in bad parms.  Your trace doesn't like the 2 get requests.  You iis logs can help but best place to check is the event logs.

Comment: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6DF8CB71-153B-4C66-8FC4-E59301B8011B}
 and APPID 
{961AD749-64E9-4BD5-BCC8-ECE8BA0E241F}
 to the user NT SERVICE\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client SID (S-1-5-80-3249811479-2167633679-2115734285-1138413726-166979568) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool. . . this is the error in system tab of event viewer

Comment: Interesting thing is that if i go to the browser console, complete html of my page is there but i dont see anything on the page and page just keeping on loading @JohnPeters

Comment: svchost (14672,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Error -1023 (0xfffffc01) occurred while opening logfile C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log.. .  this error message is also repeating very frequently in the event viewer. @JohnPeters

Comment: @WaleedNaveed Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal actually none of the answers worked for me. I checked the event logs and came to know that there was an issue in my web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the error 500.19 which is a configuration error. it means there is something wrong with your web.config file.

you could try to remove below code from your web.config file:

```
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.csharpcodeprovider, microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35" warninglevel="4" compileroptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.vbcodeprovider, microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35" warninglevel="4" compileroptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_mytype=\&quot;web\&quot; /optioninfer+" />
      </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

if you still face and issue enable detailed error in iis for your site.

1. Open the IIS console on the webserver machine.
2. Double-click the Error Pages option:

[image]

3. Select the Edit Feature Settings... option:

[image]

4. Change the default setting from the third option, Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests to the second option, Detailed errors:

[image]

5)restart iis .

Answer (score 0):

Can u try adding network service user account to the Identity of DefaultWebSite AppPool in IIS. And also same to the application root folder with all permissions.
Let me know what happens in the browser network tab.